# Relation between .NET Encoding and Characterset

Tags: c#, character-encoding, codepages

What's relation between CharacterSet here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx
and ascii encoding here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ANSI is the current Windows ANSI code page, equivalent to Encoding.Default.

OEM is the current OEM code page typically used by console applications.

You can get this using:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage)
```

In a console application, the OEM encoding will also be available using

```
Console.OutputEncoding
```

Answer (score 2):

This is really, really ancient.  ODBC dates from the stone age, back when Windows starting taking over from MS-DOS.  Back then, lots of text was still encoded in the original IBM-PC character set, named the "OEM Character Set" by Microsoft.  The standard IBM-PC set had some accented characters and pseudo graphics glyphs in the upper half, codes 0x80-0xff.

Too limited for text output in non-English languages, Microsoft started using code pages, ranges of character glyphs suitable for a certain language group.  The American English set of characters were standardized by ANSI, that label is now attached (incorrectly) to any non-OEM code page.

Nobody encodes text in the OEM character set anymore, it went the way of the dodo at least 10 years ago.  The proper setting here is ANSI.  And keeping your fingers crossed behind your back that the code page used to encode the text matches your system's default code page.  That's dodo too, Unicode solved it.

Comment: Great history yeah I guess it's not used anymore but I have to cope with old data formats at work :)

Comment: I also have to use this. Some prominent software under active development by one of the largest software vendors in the world still uses OEM codepages. - It has a long history dating back to the "stone age", though.

Comment: -1. 1) Encodings didn't go "the way of dodo" yet, every major format specifies them somehow. 2) Unicode itself has a few different representations (encodings) - Unicode is not an encoding but a character set, and encoding is a conversion between it and a byte stream.

Comment: Create batch files for the Windows console and you're still writing the "OEM" encoding today!

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question, there's no direct relation.

The longer version:
`CharacterSet` for the "Schema.ini" file can be either `ANSI` or `OEM`.
ANSI and ASCII refer to different thing.

You can read more of it here:
[Understanding ASCII and ANSI Characters](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T001787_Understanding_ASCII_and_ANSI_Characters.html)
[ASCII vs ANSI Encoding by Alex Hoffman](http://weblogs.asp.net/ahoffman/archive/2004/01/19/60094.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for links seems interesting.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, CharacterSet=ANSI is equivalent to [Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(VS.71).aspx). OEM might be ASCIIEncoding then.

However, ANSI uses the system ANSI code page, so incompatibilities may arise if the same file is accessed from computers with different code pages.

Comment: Wrong. OEM is different 8 bits than ANSI (which is `Encoding.Default`) and ASCII is 7 bits only.

Answer (score 0):

I've compiled my own reference in order to switch between the two:

```
Windows code page       Name            System.Text.Encoding    schema.ini CharacterSet
20127                   ASCII (US)      ASCII                   20127
1252                    ANSI Latin I    Default                 ANSI
65001                   UTF-8           UTF8                    65001
1200                    UTF-16 LE       Unicode                 Unicode
1201                    UTF-16 BE       BigEndianUnicode        1201
```